# How much home city reputation does each dungeon give while championing?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

One of the ways of gaining reputation for your home faction cities is by championing them (wearing their tabard) in classic dungeons. Using this method, how much reputation is gained from each dungeon assuming the following:

1. It is soloed at level 85.
2. It is fully cleared of all mobs.

I do not know if the amount is variable by character, but I receive 3 rep per trash mob and 60 rep per boss.

ETA: Per the discussion below, I'm looking for what would be considered the "base" amount of reputation, prior to racial or guild perks being applied. (I assume that the amount with the perks applied could be easily calculated from this amount depending on how Blizzard rounds and sets the order of operations.)

I am operating under the belief that all home city tabards in classic dungeons would provide the same amount of rep independent of which city is being championed. If this is incorrect, please let me know.

Comment: You can use the site [WoWJuju](http://www.wowjuju.com) to check this sort of information out based on where you are currently with that faction. They list all ways to gain rep as well, daily quests, item turn-ins, etc. Use their Rep Calculator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each instance has a different number of enemies and it is the enemies that give the reputation, rather than the instance. The number of players in the party at the time does not influence the reputation gained so whether you solo the instance or not is irrelevant. In addition to this, the instances from The Burning Crusade expansion (Hellfire Ramparts, etc) will not benefit home faction standing at all.

Reputation gained is also affected by the following factors;

- If you are Human you will gain the 'Diplomacy' racial, adding 10% additional reputation
- Guild perks provide the 'Mr. Popularity' perk, which has two levels each adding 5% additional reputation (maximum of 10%)

In order to get solid numbers, the following questions need answers;

- What is your race
- What level is your guild
- Which instance are you clearing

Assuming a full clear, you should get the following reputation per clear of each instance, bare in mind that the instances with the highest reputation per clear may not be the fastest way to grind up a reputation, as this would need to take into consideration the time it takes to clear the instance:

```
Instance Name                        Reputation per clear

Ragefire Chasm                        483
Deadmines                             810
Shadowfang Keep Normal                548 
Stormwind Stockades                   515
Scarlet Monastery Graveyard           360
Scarlet Monastery Library             353
Scarlet Monastery Armory              287
Scarlet Monastery Cathedral           448
Uldaman                               981
Scholomance                           1261
Stratholme: Main Gate                 737
Zul'Farrak                            856
Stratholme: Service Entrance          917
Temple of Atal'Hakkar                 2330
```

For the context of the question (fastest way to get reputation from Classic dungeons) I have excluded the long winded/windy instances (Wailing Caverns, Maraudon, etc) as what we're looking for is the fastest way to generate reputation. Seemingly the fastest instance to gain reputation out of the Classic instances is Sunken Temple. After the remodelling at the start of Cataclysm a large portion of this instance has been removed, leaving it as a single level instance [capable of generating 2330 reputation per run which each run taking approximately 15 minutes *on a level 60*](http://www.wowhead.com/zone=1477/sunken-temple#comments:id=1498010).

For completeness, here are the reputation values you can get per run out of a Wrath of the Lich King instance *on heroic mode*:

```
Instance Name                        Reputation per clear (HEROIC)

Ahn'kahet: The Old Kingdom            2300
Azjol-Nerub                           1300
Culling of Stratholme                 1700
Drak'Tharon Keep                      2000
Gundrak                               2250
The Nexus                             2300
The Oculus                            1600
Trial of the Champion                 180
Violet Hold                           1300
Halls of Lightening                   2150
Halls of Stone                        1850
Utgarde Keep                          1950
Utgarde Pinnacle                      2000
```

It is worth completely avoiding the likes of Trial of the Champion due to the lack of enemies present in the instance, clearing a combination of either Azjol-Nerub and Ahn'kahet: The Old Kingdom OR The Utgarde instances (Keep and Pinnacle) would probably be the fastest way to generate reputation, with these groups of instances having their entrances situated next to each other and being reasonably quick to clear.

Comment: He's specifically asking for City factions (i.e. Orgrimmar, Stormwind...)

Comment: @QAppei doesn't really change the answer in fairness, regardless of the faction without knowing which instance, how many enemies, race, guild level...

Comment: Yeah, I know, there are too many variables to consider.

Comment: This question is largely scoped but still answerable. The OP is only looking at classic dungeons and home city reputations and states that he will be killing every mob in the instance. He wants to know the rep total for each classic instance. The only real variables are race and guild perks, which a full answer could still provide details for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! -- I've edited the question for clarity and detail. It is largely scoped mostly in order to find the raw data in order to calculate the most efficient rep-grinding dungeons. (That question can't be answered in general since it's dependent on how fast a player can clear the instance.)

Comment: @dpatchery yes - the 'which faction' is an artifact from the original answer I posted which scoped out the entire faction reputation system in WoW. I have edited it out.

Comment: @Lin - the answer on this is going to take some time as I am going to have to go and clear each of these instances on a character that doesn't have max rep.

Comment: @ickleislands I am pretty sure the website [WoWJuju](http://www.wowjuju.com) already does all of the math and has all of the faction information (for more than just championing with a tabard) already calculated based on your actual characters current rep with those factions.

Comment: @Lin - the most efficient grind for rep is probably Deadmines in terms of time taken/rep gained

Comment: @Adanion unless I'm missing something, WoWJuju doesn't detail rep per instance, only rep from rewards.

Comment: @ickleislands It appears that WoWJuju doesn't list Championing for classic home factions just Championing for Lich King and Cataclysm as well as number of estimated dungeon runs for factions that give rep per kill in instances but don't have Champion tabards.

Comment: @ickleislands That said, if speed was the only requirement for gaining rep, doing lower level dungeons will only give 3 rep per elite mob and 60 rep per boss. If you do level appropriate dungeons it is 15 rep per mob and 300 rep per boss. If the dungeon being solo'able is the only requirement then I would recommend the Scarlet Monastery dungeons. You can run them all and then reset the dungeons and you shouldn't hit the reset limit per hour.

Comment: @Adanion but with that in mind, the next question is what is the OP's gear level - WOTLK instances give far more rep for a full clear and at certain gear levels will be pretty quick also.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent work, @ickleislands. (I unfortunately can't upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation...)

Comment: @Lin no problems! :)

Answer (score 0):

Blizzard has made it so that only "appropriate level" dungeons give the rep listed above. I don't know the exact levels of cutoff, but at level 100, only Wrath+ dungeons give full rep: BC and Classic give roughly 20% of the full values above.

Answer (score -1):

I know these posts are from 2012, but I wanted to give a slight update. I found this post by google when trying to figure out which classic dungeon would give the most rep while championing a faction. I saw that it listed the Temple of Atal'Hakkar as giving 2330 rep per clear. At max level now after patch 5.4 this is not true. I ran it three times back to back full clear and rep was a total of 601. I think I am gonna hit a little bit of a longer dungeon to get a greater amount of rep.