# Which Wrath of the Lich King dungeon will provide the highest rep/hour?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm farming out my LK reps (going for Beloved title, 36/70!) and I have 4 reps in LK, 3 of which must be farmed by doing dungeons.(Explorer's League, Frostborn, and Silver Covenant.)

Very soon (my guild only needs a leatherworker) I'll have access to the banner which will double my rep gains. Now this has a 10 minute CD, so I'd like to maximize that if possible.

Which dungeon will allow me to farm repeatedly and gain reputation with the tabards with the highest reputation velocity? If two of them are rather close in their xp gain, but one is linear and the other circles around, then clearly the latter would be better because I would be in range of the banner more often.

And no, this isn't on my level 1 this time. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://www.wowwiki.com/Championing) lists some rep gains from Heroic dungeons (I'm unable to confirm these values).  Notice that Heroic dungeons award 3 to 4 times the reputation compared to level 80 Normal versions.

The possible dungeons (grouped by location) are :

```
H Utgarde Keep
N/H Utgarde Pinnacle
H The Nexus
N/H The Oculus
H Halls of Stone
N/H Halls of Lightning
H Ahn'kahet: The Old Kingdom
H Azjol-Nerub
H Dark'Tharon Keep  (remote location)
H Gundrak   (remote location)
H The Violet Hold   (can't speed it up)
N/H Caverns of Time: Culling of Stratholme  (stop talking Arthas)
N/H Trial of the Champion
N/H Forge of Souls
N/H Pit of Saron
N/H Halls of Reflection
```

---

You said "repeatable", and that narrows things down considerably.  Heroic dungeons are not repeatable if you kill a boss.  Normal (80) dungeons award much less reputation compared to Heroics.

I recommend the **Pit of Saron**.  Here are the stats I've gathered (non-human with 5% rep bonus from guild reward):

```
Normal Pit of Saron, clear area before bosses: 376 rep (repeatable)
Normal Pit of Saron, full clear: 806 rep (repeatable)
Heroic Pit of Saron, clear area before bosses: 1081 rep (repeatable)
Heroic Pit of Saron, full clear: 2821 rep (once per day)
```

So, the basic idea is that you run it on Heroic, clear the area before the bosses, leave, reset, repeat.  If you clear so fast that the reset isn't available, you can knock over Heroic Forge of Souls OR Heroic Halls of Reflection while you wait.

Comment: I see - doing the heroic entry way will also facilitate easy use of the guild banner for double rep. If I can clear the entry area in 15 minutes, that's about 7k rep an hour (assuming half of the time I'm in range of the banner). Very respectable.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are able to clear trash in a very short amount of time, then run out and reset the instance, you will more than likely hit the instance per hour cap, which is 5. This disregards boss kills and as such if you step foot in the instance it will count towards your instance per hour lockout. My friends and I have run in to this several times while doing older content.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously answered this question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/74096/27134):

Each instance has a different number of enemies and it is the enemies that give the reputation, rather than the instance. The number of players in the party at the time does not influence the reputation gained so whether you solo the instance or not is irrelevant.

Reputation gained is also affected by the following factors;

- If you are Human you will gain the 'Diplomacy' racial, adding 10% additional reputation
- Guild perks provide the 'Mr. Popularity' perk, which has two levels each adding 5% additional reputation (maximum of 10%)
- World event buffs like the current Halloween world event giving an additional 10% reputation gain if you pick it up before starting

Here are the reputation values you can get per run out of a Wrath of the Lich King instance *on heroic mode*:

```
Instance Name                        Reputation per clear (HEROIC)

Ahn'kahet: The Old Kingdom            2300
Azjol-Nerub                           1300
Culling of Stratholme                 1700
Drak'Tharon Keep                      2000
Gundrak                               2250
The Nexus                             2300
The Oculus                            1600
Trial of the Champion                 180
Violet Hold                           1300
Halls of Lightening                   2150
Halls of Stone                        1850
Utgarde Keep                          1950
Utgarde Pinnacle                      2000
```

It is worth completely avoiding the likes of Trial of the Champion due to the lack of enemies present in the instance, clearing a combination of either Azjol-Nerub and Ahn'kahet: The Old Kingdom OR The Utgarde instances (Keep and Pinnacle) would probably be the fastest way to generate reputation, with these groups of instances having their entrances situated next to each other and being reasonably quick to clear.

It's worth noting that you can't repeat heroic instances, due to their lock outs, and that normal modes provide substantially less reputation. Another point of consideration is that nearly every Wrath of the Lich King reputation can be levelled by spending Justice Points at your factions vendor in Dalaran.

Comment: There's a lot of information here, but how would you max rep/hour repeatably?

Comment: The most efficient way to grind rep at max level is justice points and commendations, which is nice and repeatable. Doing normal mode dungeons is not efficient - your best bet is to do a combination of heroic dungeons and commendations

Comment: Commendations won't work for the three I need: explorere's league, the frostborn, and the silver covenant. These need to be done by killing monsters without a tabard. There's a mistake in my original post which indicates there's 4 that can be done with a tabard; only 1 can (argent crusade). I'll be using JP to get that one up, thanks to your suggesetion, but the other three will have to be grinded (ground?)

Answer (score 0):

Halls of Lightning. 3000+ per run on normal mode.
Takes about 10 minutes. Make it 12 and you won't hit the 5 dungons per hour cap.

Comment: Are you reading my mind? I was unsubscribed from WoW for over a year... I just resubscribed -LAST NIGHT-. What... the...

Comment: I got only about 1000 on normal. No rested or buffs. See the other posts for current real stats. Perhaps it changed over time?